# Execute method in a loop after a minimum time interval using Task.WhenAll or similar

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

Async beginner here, trying to improve this skill.

I want to execute a method *at most* every 500 miliseconds, or longer if a given execution takes longer than that. In that case the loop can continue imediately.

I know that I could do that with a `StopWatch` or some other timer, but I would like to do that with async/await constructs.

I developed a quick spike, but when I run it it seems to execute very tightly, and not once very 500ms or more. What am I forgeting to "await"?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Run();
        }
    }

    static async void Run()
    {
        var task1 = Task.Delay(500);
        var task2 = DoSomethingAsync();

        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
    }

    static async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int miliseconds = Convert.ToInt32(r.NextDouble() * 1000);
        await Task.Delay(miliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine(miliseconds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `Run();` to `Run().Wait()`. Sidenote: avoid `.Wait()` or `.Result` as it blocks but for this demo it will do.

Comment: @PeterBons I also got it working with `Task.WhenAll(...).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, but didn't understand why the other way didn't work, or also why I should avoid your proposed answer, and what I should use instead in production...

Comment: @L.B I must guarantee that I don't have multiple calls executing at the same time, that is, I need to be sure method is only called _after_ previous call has finished. Would `Timer` take that into account?

Comment: See this excellent guide as to why and what regarding to using the blocking options: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx. For console apps it will do.

Comment: you'r code spawns up multiple (many) tasks  which execute concurrently. all of these executions will take atlist 500 ms + the random time + some overhead of all the context switching between all these threads. is this what you were aiming for ?.it will execute them around 20 at a time , that's approximately what the amount of threads threadpool will let you use

Comment: @PeterBons my actual use case is for emptying a buffer, since I don't want a tight loop in case the buffer is empty - so I wait a bit before trying again. This would run in some class in a WPF application receiving data from a hardware. The whole thing would be executing as a delegate in a `Task.Run()` call anyway.

Comment: @eranotzap Sure, NO, my goal would be to span the next execution only after the previous one finished.

Comment: then do this Run().Wait(), and if you wan't to do it using aysnc/await 
use the await in the loop but not in main . 
in some other method which would spawn the executions

Comment: As @PeterBons says, change `Run()` to `Run().Wait()`, or to `Run().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, but also change `Run()`'s signature to `static async Task Run()`; i.e. not `void`.  How you have it in the question it'll zoom through the `while (true)` loop continually queuing more and more `Run()` tasks before they've even finished.  The rest looks fine.

Comment: Still "awaiting" an answer so that I can accept (two commenters already have it), or at least some justification for the downvote or the request for closing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not await the toplevel task (Since you do not have one). Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Run().Wait(); // Wait on each iteration.
        }
    }

    // Need to return Task to be able to await it.
    static async Task Run()
    {
        var task1 = Task.Delay(500);
        var task2 = DoSomethingAsync();

        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
    }

    static async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int miliseconds = Convert.ToInt32(r.NextDouble() * 1000);
        await Task.Delay(miliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine(miliseconds);
    }
}
```

Now, there is a catch in using `.Wait()`: it blocks execution. See this excellent guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx for more details. But don't worry, for the `Main` method of a Console App it is perfectly safe.

The same guide explains also why you should always try to return a `Task` instead of using `async void MyTask() { ... }`. In your case it prevents you from waiting for the `Run()` method to complete.